# what does this phrase "What he wouldn't give now for" mean?

Tags: rhetorical-questions

What does this sentence mean (from HarryPotter)?

> What wouldn’t he give now for a message from Hogwarts?

I don't know the grammar of this sentence. Why use "give" rather than "receive"?

Can somebody explain this sentence for me?

Comment: It's a "rhetorical question", where the expected answer would be *He would give **anything** for a message* (he values the message so highly that he would willingly ***give up/pay*** anything he has in exchange for receiving it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question pretty much means the same as: What wouldn't he do now in order to get a message from Hogwarts?

It basically means that he really wants a message from Hogwarts and would do just about anything or give just about anything (his soul, his life for example) to get what he really really wants (the letter).

Comment: The other part of the construct is that the *lack* of an answer is, in fact, the answer: i.e. nothing. There is *nothing* he wouldn't give now for a message from Hogwarts.